# Does this sequence stay within a certain range?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is $a_x = a_{x-1} + a_{1-x}$
Lets say $a_0=x$, if we solve for other numbers in the sequence, we get $a_1=a_0+a_{-0}=2a_0, a_2=a_1+a_{-1}=2a_0+a_{-1}...$ So far I have solved until $a_2$ and $a_{-2}$ and the numbers have been within 2x and -2x
The values so far are, $a_{-2}=-2x, a_{-1}=-x, a_0=x, a_1=2x, a_2=x$
Does this sequence stay within 2x and -2x or ever go to infinity?

Comment: Do you really mean that $2x \le a_n \ge -2x$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes I do, is there anything wrong?

Comment: Is $a_0$ negative? (The symbol $x$ is being used for two different things.) In any case, if the recursive definition is $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{1-n}$ for all $n\ne0$, I'm not convinced there's a unique solution. How do you justify the "values so far" for example?

Comment: This is awfully hard to follow, in part because you use $x$ to denote two unrelated things.  How do you compute $a_2$?  And writing, e.g., $a≤z≥-a$ just means that $z≥|a|$.  Is that what you meant to write?

Comment: @mathiscool The notation $a \le b \ge c$ is usually understood to mean $b \ge a$ and $b \ge c$, i.e. $b \ge \max\{a,c\}$.  This does *not* mean that $b$ is between the two values, or constrained to some range, which seems to be what you are suggesting.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ok, ill change that

Comment: @lulu x is related if $a_0=x$ then hypothetically $a_n$ is over or equals -2x and is under or equals 2x, also I forgot that i could just do |a|≤2x

Comment: $a_0 = a_{-1}+a_1$, and $a_2 = a_1+a_{-1}$, so $a_2 = a_0=x$?

Comment: @peterwhy  yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given recurrence relation,

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n} &= a_{n-1}+a_{1-n}\\
&= a_{1-(2-n)} + a_{(2-n)-1}\\
&= a_{2-n}
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively,

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n} &= a_{n-1} + a_{1-n}\\
&= a_{n-1} + a_{2-(1-n)}\\
&= a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}\\
a_{n+1} &= a_n - a_{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

As in [OEIS A057079](https://oeis.org/A057079), your sequence terms would periodically repeat $[1,2,1,-1,-2,-1]$ times $a_0$.